# Ion Auth setup on Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have setup Ion Auth on my Codeigniter 3 installation as per instructions.

When I navigate to:

```
127.0.0.1/nightmesh/auth/login
```

I am actually redirected to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/nightmesh/127.0.0.1/nightmesh/auth/login
```

My .htaccess in my root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any advice on how to avoid this?

Comment: 'When you navigate' means clicking the link or typing in URL bar?

Comment: What about other controllers/routes?

Comment: use base_url() helper instead of file name in your links see https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: @Nassim Both versions of user guide can be found here on codeigniter main website http://www.codeigniter.com/docs